What is the difference between head and tail recursion when reversing a linked list?
I am learning about different recursive approaches for reversing a linked list in C++. I have implemented both head and tail recursion methods, but I'm unsure about their differences and which one is more optimal.
Which type of recursion writing would be the optimized for reversing a linked list using recursion
1.Head recursion
2.Tail recursion

Relevant: The difference between head & tail recursion

"I have implemented both head and tail recursion methods": Please provide your implementations. "Which type of recursion writing would be the optimized": Have you done some benchmarking? What were the results?

"Tail recursion" is a very useful concept, but maybe not the first concept you should try to learn when studying recursion. "Head recursion" on the other hand, is completely useless as a concept and I can't think of a reason why someone even bothered to give it a name.

@Stef  I think our line of thinking to do a problem with recursion almost same i also found the head recursion approach to be out of box when i am randomly solving a fresh question but tail recursion is something which makes some sort of sense...

Here is my implementation using head recursion:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int val) : data(val), next(nullptr) {}
};

node* reverse(node* head) {
    if (head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr) {
        return head;
    }
    node* rest = reverse(head->next); // Reverse the rest of the list
    head->next->next = head;          // Adjust the next pointer of the next node
    head->next = nullptr;             // Set the next pointer of the current node to nullptr
    return rest;                      // Return the new head of the reversed list
}

// Helper function to print the linked list
void printList(node* head) {
    while (head != nullptr) {
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    // Create the linked list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
    node* head = new node(1);
    head->next = new node(2);
    head->next->next = new node(3);
    head->next->next->next = new node(4);
    head->next->next->next->next = new node(5);

    // Print the original linked list
    cout << "Original list: ";
    printList(head);

    // Reverse the linked list using head recursion
    head = reverse(head);

    // Print the reversed linked list
    cout << "Reversed list using head recursion: ";
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}

And here is my implementation using tail recursion:
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
        node(int val) : data(val), next(nullptr) {}
    };
    
    node* helper(node* current, node* prev) {
        if (current == nullptr) {
            return prev;
        }
        node* next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        return helper(next, current); // Tail recursion
    }
    
    node* tailReverse(node* head) {
        return helper(head, nullptr);
    }
    
    // Helper function to print the linked list
    void printList(node* head) {
        while (head != nullptr) {
            cout << head->data << " ";
            head = head->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    int main() {
        // Create the linked list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
        node* head = new node(1);
        head->next = new node(2);
        head->next->next = new node(3);
        head->next->next->next = new node(4);
        head->next->next->next->next = new node(5);
    
        // Print the original linked list
        cout << "Original list: ";
        printList(head);
    
        // Reverse the linked list using tail recursion
        head = tailReverse(head);
    
        // Print the reversed linked list
        cout << "Reversed list using tail recursion: ";
        printList(head);
    
        return 0;
    }

**Analysis
Linked List Size: 4 Nodes (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4)**
Head Recursion Approach
First call: reverse(head) where head points to node 1.
Second call: reverse(head->next) where head->next points to node 2.
Third call: reverse(head->next) where head->next points to node 3.
Fourth call: reverse(head->next) where head->next points to node 4.
Fifth call: reverse(head) where head is now nullptr.
Once the base case is reached, each of these calls returns in reverse order, making adjustments to the pointers:
The fourth call (node 4) returns.
The third call (node 3) returns, adjusting node 4's next pointer.
The second call (node 2) returns, adjusting node 3's next pointer.
The first call (node 1) returns, adjusting node 2's next pointer.
In total, there are 4 function calls to reach the base case and 4 function returns to adjust the pointers, totaling 8 function calls.
Tail Recursion Approach
First call: reverseUtil(head, nullptr) where head points to node 1 and prev is nullptr.
Second call: reverseUtil(head->next, head) where head points to node 2 and prev points to node 1.
Third call: reverseUtil(head->next, head) where head points to node 3 and prev points to node 2.
Fourth call: reverseUtil(head->next, head) where head points to node 4 and prev points to node 3.
Fifth call: reverseUtil(head->next, head) where head is nullptr and prev points to node 4.
In total, there are 4 function calls to reach the base case and 1 return from the base case, totaling 5 function calls.
Conclusion :
Head Recursion Approach: 8 function calls in total (4 calls to reach the base case and 4 returns to adjust pointers).
Tail Recursion Approach: 5 function calls in total (4 calls to reach the base case and 1 final return).

This seems to be information that belongs in the question, not in the answer section. Please edit your question and include it there. Not here.

@trincot I highly agree with you sir. I think the question should be "Which recursive approach is more optimized to reverse a linked list "head recursion" or "tail recursion"." Please you tell me how to edit the question as i am new here at this platform?

There is an edit link below your original post.

It looks like you miss the point. Please edit your question, and remove this "answer" which is not an answer.
